# Using regular expressions to parse values after a word [Nintex]

Tags: regex, parsing, nintex-workflow

I have an email that I wish to parse, its body contains stuff like

```
[Event Type]    HireEmployee
[REQUESTOR] POLM4
[SIN]   092
[Employee Name] JOHN,SMITH
[Existing payroll record]   False
[Existing PERM OA Mnemonic]
```

I need to be able to parse out the information after each header to store into a variable.

```
(\[REQUESTOR\]\t)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

will get me the line

```
[REQUESTOR] POLM4
```

but I only want it to return  "POLM4"

Thanks

EDIT:
I'm doing my testing on
http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the stuff you dont want in a non-capture group.

For example, instead of your original expression, you do:

```
(?:\[REQUESTOR\]\t)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

[image: http://www.debuggex.com/i/brf8zRxz4OcPCTjb.png]

No2 the [REQUESTOR] is in a non-capture group and the rest is in the capture group.

Non-capture groups are groups you want to check, but not have saved.

Comment: I'm finding this doesn't work. I'm using

http://regexpal.com/

for intial testing
and it still matches the whole line

Comment: Correct. It will match the whole line, but it will only return the part in the capture group. For example, if you ask `matches(regex, line)` you will get a true, but if you ask for the capture groups you will get only `POLM4` returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a positive look behind. Your regex would become for example

```
(?<=\[REQUESTOR\]\t)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

It uses [REQUESTOR] to match with but does not include it in the match itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your result `[REQUESTOR] POLM4` in a variable as var1.
and use regular expression on var1 as `^[^\)]*\]`.
This will remove the characters before `]` including `]`. So you'll get your required string as `POLM4`.